# Question about the HVZ theorem

Tags: specific-reference, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

In this paper<sup>1</sup>  the authors cite the [HVZ theorem](http://www.google.com/search?q=HVZ+theorem)<sup>2</sup> saying that it follows from the method used by M. Reed & B. Simon without modifications; I don't really understand this point.
Is there anyone who have tried to prove it?

<sup>1. Mogilner, A. I.; Shermatov, M. H., *Binding of two fermions with a third different particle by a point interaction,* Physics Letters A, Volume 149, Issue 7-8, 1990, p. 398-400.</sup>

<sup>2. (named after W. Hunziker, C. van Winter und G.M. Zhislin)</sup>

Comment: The article is behind a paywall. Please provide an arxiv-like link so that we can access to the paper.

Comment: I post this comment as an answer because I don't succed in posting it as a comment.
I have a copy of the article founded in a library; I didn't succed in finding it online.

Comment: Maybe you should try to explain the problem as it appears in the paper in your own words, and explain what you understand, and what you don't.